# How to trim a png with ImageMagick convert tool, and keep all things same distance to original center?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a png with some transparency at board, and I want to trim the transparency, and keep every thing with same distance to the original center.
I use convert tool from ImageMagick
For example,

The original one.

[image: The original]

The result I want.

[image: The correct result]

The result I use with `convert original.png -trim +repage out.png`

[image: The wrong result]

The original file is here.

[image]

Comment: So you want to trim top and bottom by the same amount as each other? And you want to trim left and right by the same as each other? But potentially you could take a different amount off the sides from the amount you remove from top and bottom? Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: And what Operating System are you using?

Comment: Yes, I want to trim the same amount from the left and right, and the same amount from the top and bottom, and also keep same ratio (width/height).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get your described result by using IM 6.8.9-9 in the ubuntu bash shell in Windows 10, running this command...

```
convert test.png -write mpr:input -duplicate 3 \
   -distort SRT %[fx:t*90] -background none -layers merge -trim \
   -set option:pagewide %[w] -set option:pagehigh %[h] -set option:pageoffset %[fx:page.x] \
   -delete 0 mpr:input -set page %[pagewide]x%[pagehigh]-%[pageoffset]-%[pageoffset] \
   -coalesce result.png
```

That reads in the input, stores one copy in temporary memory, makes 3 more copies of it, and rotates them 0, 90, 180, and 270 degrees. Then it flattens them and uses the trim results from that to calculate the final image dimensions and offsets. Next it deletes that modified image, brings the original back from temporary memory, and creates the output by applying those calculated page settings to the original.

This should work with square images. If the width and height dimensions are not the same, the calculations would become more complicated.

EDITED TO ADD: The command I've added below should take any input image and trim away as much transparent as possible while keeping the original center pixel(s) at the center of the result...

```
convert test.png -write mpr:input -background none \
   -rotate 180 mpr:input -composite -set page %[@] \
   -set option:bounds %[fx:page.width]x%[fx:page.height]-%[fx:page.x]-%[fx:page.y] \
   -delete 0 mpr:input -set page %[bounds] -coalesce result.png
```

It trims the same amount from the top and the bottom, and trims the same amount from the left and right, but the top/bottom amount may be different from the left/right amount.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running the `-trim` operation, and recording the page offsets in a temporary variable. Then calculate the final image by applying `-extent`.

For example..

```sh
# Capture original size.
read -r WIDTH HEIGHT <<<$(convert lBW9I.png -format '%[fx:page.width] %[fx:page.height]' info:-)
# Capture offset after applying trim.
read -r LEFT TOP <<<$(convert lBW9I.png -trim -format '%[fx:page.x] %[fx:page.y]' info:-)
# Use the local variables to calculate finial paging...
convert lBW9I.png \
        -background transparent \
        -extent "$(($WIDTH - $LEFT * 2))x$(($HEIGHT - $TOP * 2))+$LEFT+$TOP" \
        output.png
```

[image: With original center]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all guys. All your commands works, and because some of my picture are not square, so I finally use this command learn from imagemagick forum, it works in windows 7 with IM V7.0.7-31

```
magick lBW9I.png ( +clone -trim -set option:NTRIM %[fx:min(min(page.x,page.width-w-page.x),min(page.y,page.height-h-page.y)*page.width/page.height)]x%[fx:min(min(page.y,page.height-h-page.y),min(page.x,page.width-w-page.x)*page.height/page.width)] +delete ) -shave %[NTRIM] x.png
```